# How to define a typeclass for a binary operator?

Tags: haskell

This is a calculator that only sums numbers:

```
module Data.Calculator where

data Expr = Plus Expr Expr | Value Int

evaluate :: Expr -> Int
evaluate (Value a) = a
evaluate (Plus (Value a) (Value b)) = a + b
evaluate (Plus (Plus left right) (Value b)) = (evaluate left) + (evaluate right) + b
evaluate (Plus (Value a) (Plus left right)) = a + (evaluate left) + (evaluate right)
evaluate (Plus a@(Plus left right) b@(Plus left' right')) = (evaluate a) + (evaluate b)
```

The `evaluate` function seems way to verbose. Ideally I'd like to define a typeclass both operators and then define `Plus` as an instance of an operator, something like this:

```
class BinaryOp a where
    apply :: a -> a -> Expr

instance BinaryOp Plus where
    apply x y = x + y
```

But this obviously does not work because the type `a` that `BinaryOp` is defined with is an operator and not an operand.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Your `evaluate` function can be just

```
evaluate :: Expr -> Int
evaluate (Value x) = x
evaluate (Plus x y) = evaluate x + evaluate y
```

as all cases are accounted for.

For per the typeclass, you cannot create an instance for `Plus` since that's a constructor and you need to specify instances for types (in this case `Expr` is the type, while `Plus` and `Value` are the constructors). If you wanted a typeclass that takes two elements of a certain type and produces an `Int`, you could write something like this:

```
data Expr = Plus Expr Expr | Value Int

class BinaryOp a where
    apply :: a -> a -> Int

instance BinaryOp Expr where
    apply x y = evaluate $ Plus x y
```

Comment: If `evaluate` has type `Expr -> Int`, then I think `apply` should be `\x y -> evaluate (Plus x y)` rather than just `evaluate`.

Comment: I'd argue that using a typeclass is a bad idea here. A typeclass may be useful when there are many types involved -- here there's only one.

Comment: @AlexisKing Yes you're absolutely right thanks for catching that!